# SQL Group search results from query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the results from a select statement as seen below:

```
+-----------+-------------------------+
| city      | category                |
+-----------+-------------------------+
| Aurora    | Indian                  |
| Aurora    | Pakistani               |
| Aurora    | Restaurants             |
| Avondale  | Health & Medical        |
| Avondale  | Optometrists            |
| Brampton  | Beauty & Spas           |
| Brampton  | Hair Salons             |
| Brampton  | Indian                  |
| Brampton  | Nail Salons             |
+-----------+-------------------------+
```

I want to try group the results to something like this:

```
+-----------+-------------------------------------------------+
| city      | category                                        |
+-----------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Aurora    | Indian, Pakistani, Restaurants                  |
| Avondale  | Health & Medical, Optometrists                  |
| Brampton  | Beauty & Spas, Hair Salons, Indian, Nail Salons |
+-----------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

The code I used to extract the initial columns results was this SQL query:

```
SELECT B.City, C.Category
FROM Business B
INNER JOIN Category C
ON B.id = C.business_id
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags. Please tag a single database only.

Comment: You can use GROUP_CONCAT() or LISTAGG() and that depends o the specific database. Which database are you using?

Comment: @TheImpaler I'm using SQLite for this database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [The Impaler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6436191/the-impaler) I referenced the SQLite documentation and used *GROUP_CONCAT* to combine the results for all the categories in their subsequent cities with the following query:

```
SELECT B.City As City, GROUP_CONCAT(C.Category, ', ') As Category
FROM Business B
INNER JOIN Category C
ON B.id = C.business_id
GROUP BY B.City
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that you should use
`GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT B.City, GROUP_CONCAT(C.Category SEPARATOR ', ') as category
FROM Business B
INNER JOIN Category C
ON B.id = C.business_id
GROUP BY B.City;
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Change `SEPARATOR` by `,` and it should work in SQLite.